# Get newly added field in index using @classbridge in hibernate search

Tags: lucene, hibernate-search

I am implemeting @ClassBridge and my class is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "metaentity")
@Indexed
@ClassBridge(name="metaentityinedx",index=Index.TOKENIZED,store=Store.YES,impl = CustomBridge.class)
public class Metaentity implements java.io.Serializable {
private Long id;
@Field
private String type;
@Field
private String title;
private Set<Comment> comments = new HashSet<Comment>(0);

public Metaentity() {
}

public Metaentity(ntityByProject, String type, String title) {
    this.type = type;
    this.title = title;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Long getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name = "type", nullable = false, length = 45)
public String getType() {
    return this.type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

@Column(name = "title", nullable = false, length = 45)
public String getTitle() {
    return this.title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "metaentity")
public Set<Comment> getComments() {
    return this.comments;
}

public void setComments(Set<Comment> comments) {
    this.comments = comments;
}
```

}

and my CustomBridge.java is:

```
public class CustomBridge implements FieldBridge {

    @Override
    public void set(String name, Object value, Document document, LuceneOptions luceneOptions) {
        String hasComment="false";
        Metaentity metaentity = (Metaentity) value;
        Set<Comment> commentset = metaentity.getComments();
        if(commentset.size()>0)
            hasComment = "true";
        luceneOptions.addFieldToDocument("hasComments",hasComment, document);
    }
}
```

What i did in *CustomBridge* class is when *metaentity* has *comments>0* then set **hascomments** field to true, otherwise to false. This creates *hascomment* field in index correctly.

But when I am doing listing it just shows fields which are in *Metaentity* class not the *hascomment* field which i have indexed. I want *hascomment* field with *metaentity*.

What I can do if I want *metaentity* fields which I have defined with *hasComment* field with it. To do listing I have used:

```
   FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(session);
     Transaction tx = fullTextSession.beginTransaction();
       QueryBuilder qb = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Metaentity.class).get();                              
       org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery =  qb.keyword().onFields("hasComments").matching("true").createQuery();
        org.hibernate.Query hibQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, Metaentity.class);
        List result = hibQuery.list();

        Iterator<Metaentity> itr = result.iterator();
```

see my lucene query without using query parser, In short in my customBridge class i have added new field  "hascomment" to the index of metaentity  .When I am doing search **I want all the fields of metaentity class with "hascomment" field which I have added to the index document.**

Comment: "But when I am doing listing it just shows fields which are in Metaentity class not the hascomment field which i have indexed. I want hascomment field with metaentity." - no idea what you are saying.

Comment: Regarding the query, there is no need for a query parser when you are search for a concrete term like "true" or "false". Use a term query and actually don't tokenize the value. In this case it won't matter, but it is not needed. I recommend you to read through the Hibernate Search online documentation in quiet or even better get hold of a copy of "Hibernate Search in Action" and try to understand how this framework works before posting all these half baked code.